# Lookup Column Values

Tags: excel, vlookup

In excel, I have 3 columns, 'Group', 'Keyword', and 'Group'

The two groups are different only in the the second one has the same values twice, every time.

So I have:

```
Group       Keyword          Group

Abbeville AbbevilleColleges Abbeville
Abbotsford AbbotsfordColleges Abbeville
Aberdeen AberdeenColleges Abbotsford
Abernant AbernantColleges Abbotsford
Abernathy AbernathyColleges Aberdeen
Abilene AbileneColleges Aberdeen
```

etc...

What I want is a 4th column that will display the keywords again, but twice.

So it would look like this:

```
Group           Keyword      Group         Keyword

Abbeville AbbevilleColleges Abbeville    AbbevilleColleges
Abbotsford AbbotsfordColleges   Abbeville    AbbevilleColleges
Aberdeen AberdeenColleges   Abbotsford   AbbotsfordColleges
Abernant AbernantColleges   Abbotsford   AbbotsfordColleges
Abernathy AbernathyColleges Aberdeen     AberdeenColleges
Abilene   AbileneColleges   Aberdeen     AberdeenColleges
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas for me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just type in cell D3 = cell B2?

ie, type the equal sign, and click on whatever cell you want it to equal.  Drag this down your column to do this for all cells.  When you copy/paste or drag down, Excel is smart enough to know what pattern you're looking to replicate and will replicate that pattern.

Not sure if you're actually looking for something more complicated than this...  Or are you trying to automatically fill in the value that's in a certain cell position in relation to the current cell (ie, fill in the value of up one and over one?)

BTW - if you ever DON'T want the pattern replicated, and you want a more literal copy/paste, use dollar signs with your row/column definitions ($B$4 instead of B4)

Comment: You need two more steps and this solution works just fine. 1) Add the formula to cell D2: ``= B2``.  2) Select the range D2:D3 and drag down to the bottom of the list. As @maneesha stated, Excel is smart enough to see the pattern and copy accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, try the following formula for your 2nd keyword

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3,A3,C3)
```

where Column A is your 1st group, Column B is your Keyword and Column C is your 2nd group

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column A is Group, B is Keyword, C is Group, and D is the new Keyword column:
For the first row (row 2) just use the formula below in cell D2:

```
=B2
```

For the subsequent rows, copy down the following formula starting in cell D3:

```
=IF(D2=D1,OFFSET($B$1,ROW(D3)/2,0),D2)
```